# Is there a way to create database trigger in Memgraph by using Python-native function calls?

Tags: memgraphdb

I'd like to create and use database triggers in Memgraph. I'm using Python, so the best possible solution for me would be something that uses Python-native function calls. Is there a such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. please take a look at [GQLAlchemy](https://memgraph.com/gqlalchemy) because it's exactly what you are looking for. E.g. for triggers, there is a `DatabaseTrigger` class under `gqlalchemy/models.py` which is actually creating the database trigger under the hood (you don't have to know Cypher for that)